# Add SQLAlchemy foreign key ID to another table based on the value

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
    class User(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'user'

        id = db.Column(INT, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
        uid = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True)
        department_id = db.Column(INT, db.ForeignKey('department.id'), nullable=False)


    class Department(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'department'

        id = db.Column(INT, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
        uid = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True)
```

Whenever I am adding a new user, I always have the `name` of their department.

How can I add the new user simply with the department name without having to query the database to get the `department.id`?

Comment: That is the nature of Foreign key constraint. If you know the id before then use that otherwise, you have to fetch it from the db. And of course, your department_id column is not nullable then how do you intend to insert the row even in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way around the fact that you'll have to get the department id, if you don't have it. The usual way:

```
dep = Department.query.filter_by(name=name).one()
usr = User(..., department_id=dep.id)
```

You could also use a scalar subquery in place of the id, if you really want to avoid fetching separately:

```
dep_id = db.session.query(Department.id).filter_by(name=name).as_scalar()
usr = User(..., department_id=dep_id)
```